# Unresolved reference error in Kotlin files in a Java+Kotlin Android project

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on a Kotlin+Java hybrid project.

The Gradle version and plugin were recently upgraded to 3.1.3 and 4.4 respectively.

Now while compiling, I am getting an error of 'unresolved reference' in a few of the Kotlin files.

Eg. -

```
return when (item?.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            finish()
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

In the above code getting compilation error in android.R.id.home as unresolved reference.

Also in

```
root_low_rating_nps.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(keyboardLayoutListener)
```

Getting the 'unresolved reference' error in finding 'removeOnGlobalLayoutListener'

I have been stuck on this for 5 days.

Tried moving the Kotlin buildscript dependencies in the app module's build.gradle, invalidate caches and restart, refresh, deleting .idea/ folder.

Can anyone help resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Does the same happen when building from the command line? For example, if you run `./gradlew assembleDebug`.

Comment: @zsmb13 Yes. Same error.

Comment: I've hit with a similar issue too and worked around it by wrapping the unresolved class in a java class and using that java class in my Kotlin code… Now I'm hitting it again somewhere else… this is quite annoying… maybe downgrading Kotlin fixes it?

Comment: @CarlosFonseca Did you try the accepted solution(updating libraries)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for this.

Turns out, (and I don't know the reason why), but after upgrading the Gradle version and Kotlin plugin, the older version of a library was causing some kind of interference.
I updated

```
com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:1.3
```

to

```
com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:2.0.1
```

which was the latest available version and the issue was resolved.

If anyone else runs into this issue, try updating all your dependencies to the latest version.

And if anyone identifies the actual reason for this, please let me know as well.

Thanks